# Delphi Return Result of comparison

Tags: delphi

Is there such a function in Delphi that will return the result of a comparison.

Example:

```
label.visible := evaluate(1 > 3);
```

I have searched but I don't know what that would be called.

Comment: `1 > 3` is a boolean operation, and the result of the comparison can be directly assigned to the `Visible` property. `Label1.Visible := 1 > 3;`. This isn't an actual question, as it doesn't make sense; there's no function needed.

Comment: @KenWhite To be precise, it is an expression rather than an operation

Comment: @David: Gee. Once again, you got me. What did I do to invoke the minor syntax police this week? That's two nitpicks (1 totally uncalled for and inaccurate) today from you.

Comment: @Chris: My mistake: It's a boolean **expression**.

Comment: @KenWhite Details are important and I'm not aware of any inaccuracies in my nitpicks. I'd like to be corrected if I got something wrong.

Comment: @David, I corrected it in that post (tp which you just commented again, and I haven't yet read).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need for a Function you can just write

```
label.visible := 1 > 3;
```

since `1 > 3` is a boolean expression.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it errored out. Musta been a syntax error.

Comment: Ya. Label was just for this example.

Comment: @Chris, or, uhm, you might use the [`CompareValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Math.CompareValue) function from `Math` unit, with which you'd write a [`code like this`](http://pastebin.com/p82HJhU1), but it's like cutting an apple with a chain saw.

Comment: @TLama +1 for they apple and chain saw analogy.

Comment: Working with nothing special is fine by me.